# i can't get out put from this code?

Tags: loops

How can I get output  ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=10; j++) {
            if (j%2 !=0)
            System.out.print(j + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: i'm beginner in JS so i'm looking for to get odd number from loop? when i was searching i found this code block .it produced  out put as system.out.print.what does that mean?? when i copy paste it im my js file i ddnt get any out put.can someone explain it to me???

Comment: this is `java` code not `js` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function oddNumbers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if ((i % 2) !== 0) document.write(i + ' ');
    }
}
oddNumbers();
</script>
```

Comment: this is really helpful

Comment: Thanks..If my answer was helpful then accept it by clicking right marker and give up vote. This is the best way to appreciate the answer.